# Move website to a new domain

Tags: iis, ssl, virtualhost, domain, asp.net

At the moment, the client website (an ASP.NET app) is accessible via, let's say, `www.domain1.com`. The client has then purchased a new domain himself, e.g. `www.domain2.com`, and is wanting to switch to using his own domain name. He is looking to make the website accessible via the subdomain, `mywebsite.domain2.com`, and allow both HTTP and HTTPS protocols as well.

The thing is that he only owns the domain, `domain2.com`, but does not host any website resources, as they are all with us, which are managed by another hosting party.

So what should we do here to allow using `mywebsite.domain2.com` to access the existing website? Can we still keep the website resources with us? Also how to handle the SSL certificate in this case? Should we purchase it or should the client?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest setup I can think of is that the client can add a CNAME record for *mywebsite* and point it to www.domain1.com.

The SSL certificate is going to be an issue unless by some improbable stroke of luck we're talking about a SAN certificate that has a DNS name of both www.domain1.com and mywebsite.domain2.com. Otherwise you'll need a new SSL cert. I would guess that the responsibility depends on the agreement made.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you think if I do something like this - if I add `mywebsite.domain2.com` as a DNS domain in the hosting control panel, create DNS A record, e.g. `mywebsite.domain2.com` and point it to current IP address. Is it any different from the client adding a CNAME record?

Comment: Note, I'm not a super expert in DNS myself. I believe it should behave the same, just as long as the IP doesn't really change. That's why I went the safe route with the CNAME.